# caching snippets (modX)

Tags: caching, modx

I was simple cruising through the modx options and i noticed the option to cache snippets. I was wondering what kind of effect this would have (downsides) to my site. I know that caching would improve the loading time of the site by keeping them 'cached' after the first time and then only reloading the updates but this all seems to good to be true. My question is simple: are there any downsides to caching snippets? Cheers, Marco.

Comment: I just noticed that chunks can't be cached so this question only goes for snippets now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question!

The first rule of Modx is (almost) always cache. They've said so in their own blog.

As you said, the loading time will be lower. Let's just get the basics on the floor first. When you chose to cache a page, the page with all the output is stored as a file in your cache-folder. If you have a small and simple site, you might not see the biggest difference in caching and not, but if you have a complex one with lots of chunks-in-chunks, snippets parsing chunks etc, the difference is enormous. Some of the websites I've made goes down 15-30 levels to parse the content in come sections. Loading all this fresh from the database can take up to a coupe of seconds, while loading a flat-file would take only a few microseconds. There is a HUGE difference (remember that).

Now. You can cache both snippets and chunks. Important to remember. You can also cache one chunk while uncache the next level. Using Modx's brilliant markup, you can chose what to cache and what to uncache, but in general you want as much as possible cached.

You ask about the downside. There are none, **but** there are a few cases where you can't use cached snippets/chunks. As mentioned earlier, the cached response is divided into each page. That means that if you have a page (or url or whatever you want to call it), where you display different content based on for example GET-parameters. You can't cache a search-result (because the content changes) or a page with pagination (`?page=1`, `?page=2` etc would produce different output on the same page). Another case is when a snippet's output is random/different every time. Say you put a random quotes in your header, this needs to be uncached, or you will just see the first random result every time. In all other cases, use caching.

Also remember that every time you save a change in the manager, the cache will be wiped. That means that if you for example display the latest news-articles on your frontpage, this can still be cached because it will not display different content until you add/edit a resource, and then the cache will be cleared.

To sum it all up. Caching is GREAT and you should use it as much as possible. I usually make all my snippets/chunks cached, and if I crash into problems, that is the first thing I check.

Using caching makes your webserver respond quicker (good for the user) and produces fewer queries to the database (good for you). All in all. Caching is a gift. Use it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no downsides to caching and honestly I wonder what made you think there were downsides to it?

You should always cache everything you can - there's no point in having something be executed on every page load when it's exactly the same as before. By caching the output and the source, you bypass the need for processing time and improve performance.

Assuming MODX Revolution (2.x), all template tags you use can be called both cached and uncached.

Cached:

```
[[*pagetitle]]
[[snippet]]
[[$chunk]]
[[+placeholder]]
[[%lexicon]]
```

Uncached:

```
[[!*pagetitle]] - this is pointless
[[!snippet]]
[[!$chunk]]
[[!+placeholder]]
[[!%lexicon]]
```

In MODX Evolution (1.x) the tags are different and you don't have as much control.

Some time ago I wrote about caching in MODX Revolution on my blog and I strongly encourage you to check it out as it provides more insight into why and how to use caching effectively: https://www.markhamstra.com/modx/2011/10/caching-guidelines-for-modx-revolution/

(PS: If you have MODX specific questions, I'd suggest posting them on forums.modx.com - there's a larger MODX audience there that can help)

Comment: but (for example) would it be wise to cache an Quip form which you use as a blog. This can be updated every second so either you should then update your cache every so many seconds or you should leave it uncached, correct?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma: I have not used Quip form, but in general, if the content changes on the same page without interfering with the manager-panel (editing/adding a resource), it has to be uncached. Wile a form (just the markup for the form) can be cached because it will be the same every time.

Comment: Quip should generally be called uncached cause the content may change from pageview to pageview. You could wrap it in getCache if you want to do microcaching (ie cache it a few seconds) but not on the QuipReply form, as that may lead to unexpected results when people post a reply.

Comment: The correct URL is: https://www.markhamstra.nl/modx/general/tips-tricks-tutorials/caching-guidelines-for-modx-revolution.html